# Open Graph custom object properties: pairing objects?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, social-media

I want to create two types of custom objects. Each has a property which references an object of the other type. Essentially I want to create doubly-linked pairs of objects which have a two-way relationship. Is this a valid use case, or does it break anything?

An example:

Band: The Beatles; Members: {John, Paul George, Ringo}

Musician: Ringo; Band: The Beatles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, this is fine.

Object 1: Band
Object 2: Musician

Band references an array of Musician objects
Muscial references a Band object, or an array of band objects.

You need to set the reference to expect an array of referenced objects in the object's settings.

Comment: Thanks Simon. The documentation worried me a bit because it said Facebook only checks for object relationships 3-deep - I worried I'd be breaking something if my objects weren't defined in a pure tree structure.